# Error while using vagrant serverspec plugin

Tags: vagrant, serverspec

I am trying to use vagrant-serverspec plugin to run acceptance tests for my puppet code..but I am getting below error whenever I run it. 
Could you guys let me know what I am missing?

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/goutham27/6a56f18b4c6bb8c56a97e1dbb6c033ec/raw/38dbad99426fc3267846c43bbd73f6bc7862ddd1/serverspecerror.log

Below are versions I am using,

vagrant - 1.8.4
vagrant serverspec plugin - 1.1.1
virtualbox - 5.1.4

This is my gemfile

```
   source 'http://rubygems.org'

puppetversion = ENV.key?('PUPPET_VERSION') ? "#{ENV['PUPPET_VERSION']}" : ['= 4.3.2']
gem 'puppet', puppetversion
gem 'puppetlabs_spec_helper', '1.1.1'
gem 'puppet-lint', '1.1.0'
gem 'serverspec', '2.36.0'
gem 'facter', '2.4.6'
gem 'mocha', '1.1.0'
gem 'hiera', '3.0.6'
gem 'rake',  '10.4.2'
gem 'r10k', '2.3.0'
gem 'winrm', '1.8.1'

platforms :mswin do
  gem "win32console"
end

ruby '2.2.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue..there was serverspec gem under vagrant apart from the vagrant-serverspec plugin..I uninstalled serverspec and it is working now.

```
c:\git>vagrant plugin list
oscar (0.5.1)
serverspec (2.36.0)
vagrant-serverspec (1.1.1)
vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)
```